# How to code in java using eclipse on internet

Tags: java, eclipse, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any online IDE for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741112/is-there-any-online-ide-for-java)

Is it possible to use eclipse for java coding from internet for eg Browser based IDE or using on some server present on internet cloud?
I am using a machine on which I cannot save eclipse, and java libraries etc but can use internet.

Can anyone suggest me something.

Comment: [have a look at this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1741112/593709)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Orion](http://www.eclipse.org/orion/) it's a web based Eclipse (from the Eclipse Team)

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Install Eclipse on a computer where you can and then use one of many products to access remote computers (VNC, TeamViewer, ...)
2. Install Eclipse on a Linux box and use Linux's ability to run programs on remote machines. But here you would have to install X server on the local (the machine you cannot save Eclipse on) machine

I bet there are other options too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remote access to your own computer at home could be a solution.
Performance depends on how fast your connection is.
Ports have to be open (default: 3389).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the best way to do this would be to set up a build server (or continuous integration server) such as [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). You could then edit your code in a web editor (or simply a more lightweight editor) and just commit and push it to the build server. The build server then does all the heavy lifting and tells you if the build/passed or failed. It can even be set up to run your unit tests!

You might want to reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797090/howto-teamcity-github) in regards to tips on how to set this up. If you use Github you get the added bonus of being able to use [Ace](https://github.com/blog/905-edit-like-an-ace) to edit files - though I would suggest using a more robust editor and pushing your repository up manually.

If you are really keen on building on the internet you can check out **[compilr](http://compilr.com/)** which sounds like what you really want (though I wouldn't recommend it - you really need you own build flow!)**.

** *does not imply that the compilr service is not a good one*